# Trying to disable inactive AD Computers using Powershell using dsquery

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I know this has already been done a thousand times using Get-AdComputer but I'm trying to do it using dsquery and pipe.  I want to limit my query to a single parent OU.  Here's what I've got:

`dsquery computer "OU=Workstations,OU=Domain Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=local" -o dn -inactive 4`

As expected this gives me a list of computer distinguished names.  Move-Object can only take a distinguished name or a GUID.  I am piping it out like this:

`dsquery computer "OU=Workstations,OU=Domain Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=local" -o dn -inactive 4 | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=4WEEKS,OU=Decommissioned,OU=Domain Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=local"`

I am getting the following error for each distinguished name:

`Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: '"CN=COMPUTER1,OU=TEST,OU=Workstations,OU=Domain Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=local"' under: 'DC=contoso,DC=local'.`

So then I've tried moving them by GUID:

`$4weeks = dsquery computer "OU=Workstations,OU=Domain Computers,DC=contoso,DC=local" -o rdn -inactive 4`

This command does display a list of GUIDs:

`` $4weeks.replace("`"","") | Get-ADComputer -properties * | select Objectguid | ``

Then I'm piping it like this:

`` $4weeks.replace("`"","") | Get-ADComputer -properties * | select Objectguid | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=4WEEKS,OU=Decommissioned,OU=Domain Computers,DC=contoso,DC=local" ``

And I'm not passing through the Identity parameter properly.

`Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.`

Any suggestions?  I'm a bit new at piping.

Thanks!

Comment: the `dsquery.exe` call does NOT output _objects_ ... it outputs either a string OR an array of strings. try saving it to a $Var and seeing what the structure is. once you know that you can likely chop it into one-line strings and process it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using dsquery to find the computers, why not use dsmod/dsmove to complete the task?

```
for /f %i in ('dsquery computer "OU=Workstations,OU=Domain Computers,DC=contoso,DC=local" -inactive 4') do (
    dsmod computer %i -disabled yes
    dsmove %i -newparent "OU=4WEEKS,OU=Decommissioned,OU=Domain Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=local"
)
```

**Note** To use this in a batch file you need to double up %

To answer your specific question, you'd need to construct an object before piping as powershell expects objects to come down the pipeline. It's probably easier to just use the text through a `Foreach-Object` loop

```
dsquery computer "OU=Workstations,OU=Domain Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=local" -o dn -inactive 4 | Foreach-Object {
    Move-ADObject -Identity ($_ -replace '"') -TargetPath "OU=4WEEKS,OU=Decommissioned,OU=Domain Computers,DC=Contoso,DC=local" -PassThru | 
        Set-ADComputer -Enabled $false
}
```

**Note** The double quotes that dsquery adds to the distinguished name need to be removed. That is why `-Identity ($_ -replace '"')` is present